# What does `Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread` mean?

Tags: python, c++, boost, mpi, message-passing

I am passing an mpi communicator from python to C. I chose to use boost's mpi communicator as mpi4py does not seem to have good C support. Check it out:

```
        try: from boost.mpi import world
        except ImportError: from mpi import world
        err = run_with_mpi(infile, world, stdout, stderr, exc)
```

On systems where boost.mpi is installed, this raises no errors. However, boost.mpi cannot be installed on mac. I installed boost's mpi.so module using homebrew's boost155 formula then added the .so file to pythonpath.

Generally, what does `Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread` mean? What clues does this message give to developers like myself?

Full error message:

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
[kilojoules-20160s:64471] *** Process received signal ***
[kilojoules-20160s:64471] Signal: Abort trap: 6 (6)
[kilojoules-20160s:64471] Signal code:  (0)
[kilojoules-20160s:64471] *** End of error message ***
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem may occur if the `.so` file from homebrew's formula links against a different `python` library than the interpreter you are running, see also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678153/homebrew-python-on-mac-os-x-10-8-fatal-python-error-pythreadstate-get-no-cu) and [this response](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/1806/).

If you have no other dependencies then running your program using the python interpreter from homebrew (which should be located in `/usr/local/bin/`) may solve the issue.