# Error with sys.path.append and module

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pycharm

I am a newbie with Python and I always run scripts with terminal. Now I would like to run and debug using PyCharm. I have this script:

```
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

matplotlib.use('Agg')
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import os
import math
import time
from time import sleep
import fpformat
sys.path.append("/Users/myname/OneDrive - UCL/my_folder/build")
from my_module_name import example
```

When I run the script with terminal everything works.
When I use PyCharm I have this:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 "/Users/myname/OneDrive - UCL/my_folder/Simulations/S16/03/04_Command_compacity/8.Compact_resistance.py"
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
```

The problem is here:

```
sys.path.append("/Users/myname/OneDrive - UCL/my_folder/build")
from my_module_name import example
```

I have to use this module for my master thesis and if I remove these two lines I can run other scripts, but I can't run scripts that use this module.
Could you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Is `gmshutils` specifically imported in `my_module_name`?  Where does `gmshutils` reside?  For example, if it was installed in the current directory then that is often something which is different in an IDE.

Comment: @cdarke I don't use that module, so that info is ok. Thanks, I forgot to remove that line from my post. I edit it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \`Fatal Python error: PyThreadState\_Get: no current thread\` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640529/what-does-fatal-python-error-pythreadstate-get-no-current-thread-mean)

Comment: `In other words, you have more than one version of python installed and Pycharm is picking-up the wrong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typed

```
which python
```

in terminal and I changed the directory in the Python Interpreter settings